# Check if All Values Exist as Keys in Dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list of values, and a dictionary. I want to ensure that each value in the list exists as a key in the dictionary. At the moment I'm using two sets to figure out if any values don't exist in the dictionary

```
unmapped = set(foo) - set(bar.keys())
```

Is there a more pythonic way to test this though? It feels like a bit of a hack?

Comment: `all([x in bar.keys() for x in foo])`?

Comment: `all(i in dct for i in vals)` would have the same time complexity, your method works fine though.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I thought that the time complexity of iterating over the list was going to be higher than what it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach will work, however, there will be overhead from the conversion to `set`.

Another solution with the same time complexity would be:

```
all(i in bar for i in foo)
```

Both of these have time complexity `O(len(foo))`

```
bar = {str(i): i for i in range(100000)}
foo = [str(i) for i in range(1, 10000, 2)]

%timeit all(i in bar for i in foo)
462 µs ± 14.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit set(foo) - set(bar)
14.6 ms ± 174 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# The overhead is all the difference here:

foo = set(foo)
bar = set(bar)

%timeit foo - bar
213 µs ± 1.48 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The overhead here makes a pretty big difference, so I would choose `all` here.

Comment: Thanks. I was going to use comprehension first, but then had a moment where I completely forgot how dictionaries work. The comprehension feels more pythonic too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to see if there is any unmapped item:

```
has_unmapped = all( (x in bar) for x in foo   )
```

To see the unmapped items:

```
unmapped_items = [ x for x in foo if x not in bar ]
```