# set issubset performance difference depending on the argument type

Tags: python, performance, set

**why this question ?**

I was trying to answer this question: [Check if All Values Exist as Keys in Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724875/check-if-all-values-exist-as-keys-in-dictionary) with something better than a generator comprehension fed to `all` (python loops, even in comprehensions, slow down execution compared to implicit loops that some functions perform):

```
all(i in bar for i in foo)
```

where `bar` is a dictionary and `foo` is a list by using `set.issubset` (with a conversion to `set` of `foo` to be able to use `foo.issubset(bar)`), and didn't succeed to beat the times of the `all` solution (unless both containers are converted to `set`s).

**my question:**

From the documentation of [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

> Note, the non-operator versions of union(), intersection(), difference(), and symmetric_difference(), issubset(), and issuperset() methods will **accept any iterable as an argument**. In contrast, their operator based counterparts require their arguments to be sets. This precludes error-prone constructions like set('abc') & 'cbs' in favor of the more readable set('abc').intersection('cbs').

Okay but the performance really depends on the type of argument, even if the complexity does not ([The complextiy of Python issubset()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674289/the-complextiy-of-python-issubset)):

```
import timeit
foo = {i for i in range(1, 10000, 2)}
bar = foo - {400}
n=10000
x = timeit.timeit(setup="foo = {str(i) for i in range(1, 10000, 2)};bar = foo - {'400'}",stmt="bar.issubset(foo)",number=n)
print("issubset(set)",x)
x = timeit.timeit(setup="foo = {str(i) for i in range(1, 10000, 2)};bar = foo - {'400'};foo=list(foo)",stmt="bar.issubset(foo)",number=n)
print("issubset(list)",x)
x = timeit.timeit(setup="foo = {str(i):i for i in range(1, 10000, 2)};bar = set(foo) - {'400'}",stmt="bar.issubset(foo)",number=n)
print("issubset(dict)",x)
x = timeit.timeit(setup="foo = {str(i):i for i in range(1, 10000, 2)}.keys();bar = set(foo) - {'400'}",stmt="bar.issubset(foo)",number=n)
print("issubset(dict_keys)",x)
```

my results (Python 3.4):

```
issubset(set) 1.6141405847648826
issubset(list) 3.698748032058883
issubset(dict) 3.6300025109004244
issubset(dict_keys) 4.224299651223102
```

So if a `set` is passed as the argument, the result is very fast.

Using a `list` is much slower. I figured out that it was because of the hash that must be done on the strings is costly. So I changed my test inputs with integers like this:

```
foo = {i for i in range(1, 10000, 2)}
bar = foo - {400}
```

and the results were globally faster but still a huge time difference:

```
issubset(set) 0.5981848205989139
issubset(list) 1.7991591232742143
issubset(dict) 1.889119736960271
issubset(dict_keys) 2.2531574114632678
```

I also tried to change `dict` by `dict.keys()` as in python 3 the keys is said to be (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/) "a set-like or unordered container object".

But in that case, the result is even worse than with `dict` or `list`.

**So why does passing a `set` beats passing a `list` or a `dict` or a `dict_keys` object?** I don't see anything mentionned in the documentation about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`set.issubset` algorithm](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Objects/setobject.c#L1777) requires a set to work with (frozensets and subclasses count); if you pass it something else, it will make a set. It's basically `all(elem in other for elem in self)`, and it needs to know that `elem in other` is efficient and means what it means for sets. The only way it knows how to guarantee that is to ensure `other` is a set. Making a set is expensive.

(I've glossed over some details. If you want to know exactly what's going on, particularly if you have a weird set subclass, read the source code in the link.)

Comment: I expected it probably could be made to work with dict key views (which are sufficiently set-like) but nobody bothered to implement that in CPython yet.

Comment: Seems like `PyAnySet_Check` does allow for frozenset and set subclasses.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: As wim said, `frozenset`s count as sets for the purpose of this check. (The same exact routine is used for `set.issubset` and `frozenset.issubset`, and it accepts the same argument types regardless of the type of `self`.)