# Checking for two numbers in list without going through list twice in the shortest, human-readable way

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

So, I want to check if either integers a or b are in a list.

Without going through the list twice, I can do this:

```
def hasab(nums):
  for i in nums:
    if(i == a or i == b):
      return True
  return False
```

However, I was wondering if this could be shortened to one-two lines, but only could find a way that would iterate through the list twice:

```
def hasab(nums):
  return a in nums or b in nums
```

If it is possible to create a one-liner that is short, iterates through the list once at most, and is decently human readable, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Why the quest for a 1-liner? If your code works, it's not really an on-topic question here because it's probably a cosmetic change

Comment: Use `any` and short-circuit: `any(i in {a, b} for i in nums)`

Comment: Is the one-pass requirement about efficiency? If so, you're overestimating the importance of making one pass or two.

Comment: make `nums` a `set`, then you can do `nums.issuperset({a,b})`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Are you sure? It's an `or`, not `and` condition...

Comment: oh right. Then `not nums.isdisjoint({a,b})`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, better :)

Comment: A nice, readable on-liner is a good goal. Avoiding going through a list twice is also a good goal. But that does not mean that either of those are going to make your code any faster. Going through a list twice to compare with one character each time seems abut the same as going through the list once to compare with two characters. There are 2*N comparisons involved.

Comment: @zvone except that the current code can short-circuit due to the `return`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the main issue here is that you seem to require that `nums` is a `list`, where - since integers are hashable -, `nums` could be/start as a `set`. In that case:

```
def hasab(nums):
  return a in nums or b in nums
```

would be the fastest way to test this, and in that case `in` doesn't "iterate" in the `set`. The values are hashed and tested with an average `O(1)` time. That plus short-circuit makes that very fast.

Of course, `nums` should not be converted from `list` to `set` each time, or that would be useless.

For more elements (or an unknown number of elements), you may consider using `any`:

```
return any(x in nums for x in [a,b,c,d,...])
```

If your data also comes in a `set`, then the best way is to test if both sets aren't disjoint:

```
return not nums.isdisjoint(input_set)
```

`isdisjoint` is really performant only if inner argument is a `set` (for more details: [set issubset performance difference depending on the argument type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50728117/set-issubset-performance-difference-depending-on-the-argument-type))

So just make sure you're creating/maintaining `nums` as a `set`, not a `list` and you'll have fast & readable constructs at your disposal.

Comment: But isn't converting to a set `O(n)`? In their current approach, it's possible the loop breaks on the first item in the list

Comment: `nums` should be a `set` in the first place, or this isn't very interesting

Comment: If you want to use `isdisjoint`, `not {a, b}.isdisjoint(nums)` works without requiring `nums` to be a set (and without converting `nums` to a set internally).

Comment: yes, but it's really slower: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50728117/set-issubset-performance-difference-depending-on-the-argument-type

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Note that that was `issubset`, not `isdisjoint`. There is a performance difference with set or non-set arguments to `isdisjoint`, but the analysis is different; with `isdisjoint`, the extra cost of a non-set argument comes from having to use generic iteration and not having precomputed hashes to work with. With `issubset`, it converts non-set arguments to sets under the hood.