# What is the most efficient way to compute the difference of lines from two files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, performance, difference

I have two lists in python `list_a` and `list_b`. The `list_a` have some images links, and the `list_b` too. 99% of the items are the same, but i have to know this 1%. The all surplus items are in `list_a`, that means all items in `list_b` are in `list_a`. My initial idea is subtract all items:
`list_a - list_b = list_c`, where the `list_c` are my surplus items. My code is:

```
list_a = []
list_b = []
list_c = []

arq_b = open('list_b.txt','r')
for b in arq_b:
    list_b.append(b)

arq_a = open('list_a.txt','r')
for a in arq_a:
    if a not in arq_b:
        list_c.append(a)

arq_c = open('list_c.txt','w')
for c in list_c:
    arq_c.write(c)
```

I think the logic is right, if i have some items, the code is run fast. But i dont have 10 items, or 1.000, or even 100.000. I have **`78.514.022`** items in my `list_b.txt` and **`78.616.777`** in my list `list_a.txt`. I dont't know the cost of this expression: `if a not in arq_b`. But if i execute this code, i think wont finish in this year.

My pc have 8GB, and i allocate 15gb for swap to not explode my RAM.

My question is, there's another way to make this operation more efficiently(Faster)?

- The `list_a` is ordinate but the `list_b` not.
- Each item have this size: `images/00000cd9fc6ae2fe9ec4bbdb2bf27318f2babc00.png`
- The order doesnt matter, i want know the surplus.

Comment: Does the order matter? If not, try using sets. With sets, subtraction should be linear: `set_c = set_a - set_b`.

Comment: But is possible make this in python?

Comment: The python will use the most efficient way to make this operation?

Comment: Yes, I mean the Python datatype [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Comment: @tripleee It's not a duplicate of that - that question is about mapping subtraction over a list, this question is about the difference between what's included in the lists.

Comment: this isn't a duplicate of the question linked. Please don't roboclose...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can create one set of the first file contents, then just use `difference` or `symmetric_difference` depending on what you call a difference

```
with open("list_a.txt") as f:
    set_a = set(f)

with open("list_b.txt") as f:
    diffs = set_a.difference(f)
```

if `list_b.txt` contains more items than `list_a.txt` you want to swap them or use `set_a.symmetric_difference(f)` instead, depending on what you need.

`difference(f)` works but still has to construct a new `set` internally. Not a great performance gain (see [set issubset performance difference depending on the argument type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50728117/set-issubset-performance-difference-depending-on-the-argument-type)), but it's shorter.

Comment: Nice, this avoids having to allocate space for the second set.

Comment: Well, not really, because internally a `set` is created, then thrown away. but it's thrown away _faster_

Comment: But the complexity is the same of subtract sets?

Comment: @ViniciusMorais The time complexity is the same, the space complexity (apparently), too.

Comment: @L3viathan In case the original list (the original set) is not needed anymore you can use `difference_update`. This should not require to allocate a new set internally.

Answer (score 11):

Try using sets:

```
with open("list_a.txt") as f:
    set_a = set(f)

with open("list_b.txt") as f:
    set_b = set(f)

set_c = set_a - set_b

with open("list_c.txt","w") as f:
    for c in set_c:
        f.write(c)
```

The complexity of subtracting two sets [is O(n) in the size of the set a](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: You know - an open file is an iterator - therefore you can simply do `set_a = set(open("list_a.txt"))`

Comment: yes but doing `set(f)` in with block ensures that it closes the file

Answer (score 2):

To extend the comment of @L3viathan
If order of element is not important set is the rigth way.
here a dummy example you can adapt:

```
l1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = [3,4,5]
setL1 = set(l1)  # transform the list into a set
setL2 = set(l2)
setDiff = setl1 - setl2  # make the difference 
listeDiff = list(setDiff)  # if you want to have your element back in a list
```

as you see is pretty straightforward in python.

Answer (score 2):

In case order matters you can presort the lists together with item indices and then iterate over them together:

```
list_2 = sorted(list_2)
diff_idx = []
j = 0
for i, x in sorted(enumerate(list_1), key=lambda x: x[1]):
    if x != list_2[j]:
        diff_idx.append(i)
    else:
        j += 1
diff = [list_1[i] for i in sorted(diff_idx)]
```

This has time complexity of the sorting algorithm, i.e. O(n*log n).